# Anaconda launcher won't open

Tags: anaconda

I downloaded anaconda but when I click on the launcher application it doesn't open. I have tried to update it in terminal but it says command not found. How can I fix this?

Comment: In the terminal, you might need to use the path to anaconda, e.g. `~/anaconda/bin/conda`.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to fixing the path issues, as suggested by Thomas.
(Assuming you didn't press yes wen the installer asked if you wanted to prepend the Anaconda install location to your PATH)

It might just help to install the launcher:

```
>> conda install launcher
```

Answer (score 1):

Anaconda Navigator stopped working after running TensorFlow script.

I reinstalled a new version of Anaconda. That did not fix the problem.

I followed a advice from:
https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/910
that did not fix the problem either.

Finally I tried this and it worked:

`sudo rm -rf ~/.continuum/`

Somehow ~/.continuum/ was owned by root.

Comment: I am having same problem after doing same thing. But I don't see any ~/.continuum/ directory.

Comment: I no longer have a 

`~/.continuum/`

I do have a:

`~/.conda/`

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, I used spyder directly from here:
C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Scripts\spyder.exe
This is good to start coding.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the permission question, using the iterm run anaconda-navigator, you will get the error message.
If it's the permission question, just rename the permission file.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this command:

```
 python -m pip install jupyter notebook
```

then
just type:

```
  jupyter notebook
```

it will work accurately.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem on my mac. Deleted the `config.yaml` file inside the binstar folder

`/Users/<user_name>/Library/Application Support/binstar` by using the command

`rm -rf config.yaml`

and it worked. I could open anaconda navigator.